# space bar dismissing alerts

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, alert

I have a technical issue whereby if a space is typed into an input box, it alerts 'no spaces allowed', however as the space bar can also be used to dismiss alerts, it immediately disappears upon key-up . So the alert just flashes then its gone, unless you hold down the space bar. Can anyone figure out how to solve this issue? Thanks.

```
$('#email').bind('DOMAttrModified textInput input change keypress paste',function(){  

   if($(this).val().match(/[\s]/g)) {
     alert("email should not contain spaces");
   } 
});
```

Comment: Have you tried to bind on keyup rather than keypress?

Comment: I have yes, it's the same issue

Comment: put the event in the function params and try `ev.preventDefault()` or `stopPropagation()`... somehow this should stop it from bubbling up to the alert

Comment: @Tallmaris: that's not going to work.  Events bubble up the document tree, they don't propagate to other windows like modal alert boxes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using a JavaScript modal, you can create your own.  You could use jQuery UI dialog, but it's not that difficult to do.

Also the fact that you are binding to all of those different kind of events can cause some of them to fire multiple times inappropriately.  You can check whether you are already in the process of warning the user with a simple data flag.

```
$('#email').bind('DOMAttrModified textInput input change keypress paste', function (e) {
    var $this = $(this);
    if ($this.val().match(/[\s]/g) && !$this.data('spacedout')) {
        $this.data('spacedout', true);
        $("<div>").appendTo("body").css({
            position: 'fixed',
            width: '100%',
            height: '100%',
            backgroundColor: 'black',
            opacity: '0.7',
            top: 0,
            left: 0
        }).append($("<div style='color: red;'>Spaces not allowed<br><input type=submit value=OK></div>").on('click', function () {
            $this.data('spacedout', false).trigger('focus');
            $(this).parent().remove();
        }));
        $this.trigger('blur');
    }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ExplosionPIlls/HwYdF/

Answer (score 1):

You can try this :

before showing an alert bind `keydown` on your `document`

```
alert("email should not contain spaces")
$('document').keydown(function(event) {
        if (event.keyCode == 32) {
            event.preventDefault();
        }
    });
```

and unbind this when user clicks or type on your input.

I would also recommend using some notification plugin like [this](http://pinesframework.org/pnotify/) instead of showing alerts.

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend using an unobtrusive validation method. This can be done *very* easily with something like [colorbox](http://www.jacklmoore.com/colorbox/) (although this is still somewhat obtrusive - ideally don't even leave focus of the control, if you can!*), and can be as simple or complex as you like, without irritating users to their wits end and half to death with archaic modal dialog boxes. For example:

```
$.colorbox( html: '<p>Your message</p>', show: true );
```

<sub>* I keep seeing [noty](http://needim.github.com/noty/) crop up in searches for things I need to do and I'm eager to use it; until then I can't vouch for it but can offer it as *something like* you could use to give 'inline validation'.</sub>

Comment: thanks for the suggestion. I am going to look into color boxes. alerts are kind of a pain.